# How to split a string column into rows including NULLs?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I want to split a string column into rows including NULL values.

I use the following, however, it doesn't return NULL rows.
Is there another way of achieving this without eliminating NULL rows?

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(s.value, '[{}_]', ' ')) AS extracted
FROM t1, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(val, ',') s
```

**Here is the example data:**

[image]

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '{Other}' AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, NULL AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, '{Other Questions,Missing Document}' AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, NULL AS val )
```

**Desired output:**

```
+----+------------------+
| id |    extracted     |
+----+------------------+
| A  | Other            |
| A  |                  |
| A  | Other Questions  |
| A  | Missing Document |
| A  |                  |
+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an IFF on the lateral split to table:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '{Other}' AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, NULL AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, '{Other Questions,Missing Document}' AS val UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, NULL AS val )


SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(s.value, '[{}_]', ' ')) AS extracted
FROM t1, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(iff(val is null, '', val), ',') s

;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(s.value, '[{}_]', ' ')) AS extracted
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t1.val, ',') s
     ON 1=1;
```